# Drupal 7- Anonymous users denied access to some pages

Tags: drupal-7, access-denied

I have a Drupal 7 site with 3 languages- English (default), Korean, and Spanish.

On certain pages (user profile, 2 different custom content types), anonymous users get access denied error messages when viewing the pages on the Korean or Spanish versions, but can see the content fine on the English version.

Logged in users can see the pages without any problem, and other custom content types don't have this issue.

I tried flushing the cache (multiple times) and rebuilding permissions (multiple times) to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Is the [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) module enabled? If so try looking into the settings for that.

Comment: No- that would have been one of the first things I checked.